# Kubernetes deployment cannot use volume mount

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a custom kubernetes cluster with local disk `PersistentVolume`s. I am trying to deploy spring-cloud-dataflow using [this guide](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/helm/#configuration-and-installation-details).

However, none of the pods are able to write on persistent volumes mounted. Here are the errors.

```
│
│ mariadb 12:55:19.88 INFO  ==> Validating settings in MYSQL_*/MARIADB_* env vars                                                                                       │
│ mariadb 12:55:19.89 INFO  ==> Initializing mariadb database                                                                                                           │
│ mkdir: cannot create directory '/bitnami/mariadb/data': Permission denied
```

```
│ zookeeper 12:55:47.87 INFO  ==> ** Starting ZooKeeper setup **  
│
│ mkdir: cannot create directory '/bitnami/zookeeper/data': Permission denied                                                                                           │
│ Stream closed EOF for default/spring-cdf-release-zookeeper-0 (zookeeper)
```

I have tried adding `initContainers` but did not help.

```yaml
rabbitmq:
  enabled: false

mariadb:
  initContainers:
  - name: take-data-dir-ownership
    image: docker.io/bitnami/minideb:stretch
    command:
    - chown
    - -R
    - 777:777
    - /bitnami/mariadb
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 0
    volumeMounts:
    - name: data-spring-cdf-release-mariadb-0
      mountPath: /bitnami/mariadb

kafka:
  enabled: true
  initContainers:
  - name: take-data-dir-ownership
    image: docker.io/bitnami/minideb:stretch
    command:
    - chown
    - -R
    - 777:777
    - /bitnami/kafka
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 0
    volumeMounts:
    - name: data-spring-cdf-release-kafka-0
      mountPath: /bitnami/kafka

zookeeper:
  enabled: true
  initContainers:
  - name: take-data-dir-ownership
    image: docker.io/bitnami/minideb:stretch
    command:
    - chown
    - -R
    - 777:777
    - /bitnami/zookeeper
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 0
    volumeMounts:
    - name: data-spring-cdf-release-zookeeper-0
      mountPath: /bitnami/zookeeper
```

#### Any suggestions how can I make this volume writable by the pod?

Comment: did you tried with changing the `fsgroup` permission in a security context?

Comment: No exactly sure what that is @HarshManvar. Could you point me to some resources?

Comment: `securityContext:runAsUser: 0, fsgroup:0` ref : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-pod

Comment: `unknown field "fsgroup" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.SecurityContext`

Comment: It is getting set at container level ? Set it at pod level instead container level

Comment: @HarshManvar here are my new values in `initContainer` but they don't seem to work.

Comment: don't put it in the init container try on the POD level, outside of the init container:  if you notice in this example : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-pod it's right after spec: